# 行列の各要素の値を参照して抽出する方法

Tags: python, python3

ある行列の固有ベクトル(`numpy.ndarray`)を計算して転置したものがあります（各列が各固有値に対応しています）
その固有ベクトルの中から`0`でない最も低い値を`t`個抜き出して`list`に保存したいのですが、方法がわからずに困っています。

例として以下のような行列を用意しました。

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
A = np.array([[3, 2, 0], [2, 9, 2], [0, 2, 7]])
w, v = LA.eig(L)
eigenvector = v.T
```

例の行列では固有ベクトルが０ベクトルになっていないですが、０ベクトルがある行列にも対応できように０を`t`個分`list`に加えるようにもしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 方法の一つとして `np.sort(eigenvector[np.nonzero(eigenvector)])[:t]` が考えられます。

Comment: @metropolis アドバイスありがとうございます。この方法だと１個目の固有値に対応する固有ベクトルをリストに保存している様ですが、それを全固有値に対応する方法(n*tのリスト)はありますか？

Comment: そうですね、`np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[np.nonzero(x)][:t], 0, np.sort(eigenvector, axis=0)).T` でしょうか？(結果はリストではなく `numpy.ndarray` 型になりますけれども)

Comment: @metropolis 何度も申し訳ありません。上の例ではうまくいったのですが、別の行列で試したところ`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)`というエラーが出ました。明確な違いは非対称行列を扱ったくらいなのですが、対処法などはありますか？なお、非対称行列ですが固有値は実数です。

Comment: numpy.ndarray の場合、各行のカラム数が一致している必要があります。つまり、固有ベクトル内の 0 ベクトルの個数が `n - t` よりも多くなっている事かと思います。`0` をパディングするのであれば、`np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.r_[(c:=x[np.nonzero(x)])[:t], np.zeros(max(0, t-c.shape[0]))], 0, np.sort(eigenvector, axis=0)).T` となりますが、`:=` 演算子(Walrus operator)を使用していますので Python 3.8 以降で実行する必要があります。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。その方法で解決できました。